# jQuery: live() vs delegate()

Tags: javascript, live, jquery

I'm using jQuery in my web application. While reading its documentation I read about `live()` and `delegate()`. Although they have explained both methods, I don't understand the exact difference between them. Also not sure about which method is ideal in which scenario.

Please help me to get clear understanding of these methods.

Thanks

Comment: A concise summary: [JQuery -- live vs delegate](http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2011/oct/jquery_live_vs_delegate).

Comment: In addition to the answer below, readers might want to have a look at this *unbelievably good* [article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) explaining the difference between `bind`, `live` and `delegate`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) requires you run the selector immediately, unless you're using the result it's very wasteful.  The event handler here is attached to `document`, so all event of that type from any elements bubbling must be checked.  Here's a usage example:

```
$(".myClass").live("click", function() { alert("Hi"); });
```

Note that the statement `$(".myClass")` ran that selector to find all elements with that class *even though we don't care about them*, all we *wanted* was the string `".myClass"` to match *later* when `click` events bubble up to `document`.

---

[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) actually uses [`.live()`](http://[%60.live()%60][1]) internally, but with a context.  The selector is *not* run immediately, so it's more efficient already, and it doesn't attach to `document` (though it can) it's much more local...and all those *other* events from other element trees you don't care about are never even checked when bubbled...again more efficient.  Here's a usage example:

```
$("#myTable").delegate("td", "click", function() { alert("Hi"); });
```

Now what happened here? We ran `$("#myTable")` to get the element to attach to (admittedly more expensive than `document`, but we're *using* the result.  Then we attach an event handler to that (or those in other cases) elements.  Only `clicks` from *within* that element are checked against the `"td"` selector when they happen, not from *everywhere* like `.live()` does (since *everything* is inside `document`).

Comment: Great explanation, live always smelled funny to me. It's much better to restrict your handlers just to the portion you care about.

Comment: See some performance benchmarks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690370/live-vs-bind/7692651#7692651

Answer (score 6):

*delegate()* maps to *live()* in the jQuery code.  The main difference is that *live()* is called on an element for which you wish to delegate the events to a different element.  *live()* will delegate these events to the *document* object.

*delegate()*, on the other hand allows you to set which element events are delegated to by passing a selector.  Events that bubble up to that element are handled if the originating element matches the selector.

As @NickCraver [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate/4204349#4204349), *delegate()* performs better than live because it doesn't necessarily capture events from every element on the page, and it doesn't query the selector right away.

Answer (score 3):

From jQuery Documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Live Method:

```
$("#mymethod").live("click", function() { alert("It checks the entire DOM"); });
```

Live Method Checks #mymethod in Entire DOM (Sometimes it will take time based on your DOM Contents)

Delegate Method:

```
$('.mycontainer').delegate('#mymethod','click',function() { alert('Checks only in mycontainer portion') });
```

Delagate does not search your whole DOM it searches only in your mycontainer portion.(Improve Performance)