# jquery and ajax problem

Tags: ajax, jquery

i am using jquery and ajax.

i have some divs with ids like id="apple-23" , id="apple-45" and ...

i have some jquery code like this:

```
 $("[id^=apple]").click(function(){
     elid = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
     pid = elid[1];
     alert(pid);
 });
```

the code works well for these divs.

but the ajax also return similar divs with similar id pattern like id="apple-61" and etc.
but the jquery code doesn't work for these ajax produced divs.

why is it so? and how can i solve it?

Comment: Do you have a common parent for these divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `.delegate()` or `.live()` to handle events on elements that don't exist yet.

If these divs have a common parent, it's more efficient to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `.live()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate/4204349#4204349)).

```
$("#divContainer").delegate("[id^=apple]", "click", function(){
     elid = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
     pid = elid[1];
     alert(pid);
});
```

Comment: so if i have a parent for them using delegate() is more faster than live().because live attached to document and check the whole document to detect matched elements but delegate() only check some specific elements to find matched elements to attach event.is it right?

Comment: @hd: Yes, that's how I understand it. From that link, `delegate` actually calls `live` but limits its scope to the container, whereas `live` on it's own just delegates to the document.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are binding the event before the elements exist.

Use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead (assuming you are using jQuery 1.3+):

```
$("[id^=apple]").live("click", function(){
     elid = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
     pid = elid[1];
     alert(pid);
 });
```