# Bind to anchor in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.notifypop").bind('click', function(){
       // Do stuff
       return false
   });
});
```

When I replace the content of the page I also replace the anchor that I have bound the click event to. The result is that the click event is no longer bound to the anchor - what to do in that situation? I HAVE to replace the anchor.

- Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.delegate` instead. `.delegate` is significantly cheaper then `.live` And will bind to all all elements matching the selector.

See the documentation on [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$("body").delegate("a.class", "click", function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

See [Nick Craver's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate/4204349#4204349) Answer as to why `.delegate` is better

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind with `.live`, not `.bind`. `.bind` only applies to objects that exist at DOM load. Anything you create via JS, jQuery, AJAX, etc. that didn't exist at page load must be bound with `.live` for functionality.

```
$("a.notifypop").live('click', function(){
  // Do stuff
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your new anchor has the same class:

```
$('a.notifypop').live('click', function(){
});
```