# jQuery .live event propagation

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, jquery

I have a little problem with jQuery `.live` method. I am using it for catching ajax events for Google Analytics on my website, but in case I have a link with an inner image, the click event is fired up from the image and my live binded click event does not catch it.

I really dont like to add these events manually everytime after changing content and I dont like to bind it to the image (because of the missing href parameter, this case I had use some .parent method), so what is the best way how to handle this?

Notice: I am not sure about efficiency of the .live method, so in case there are big performance differences, please tell me that:) I tried to profile it in webkit profiler, but I didn't see any difference..

Comment: The live method is only relevant if you are dynamically adding content to your page, otherwise just use the standard selectors.

Comment: The following test works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NxNkk/. Maybe post some code, and I can say more.

Comment: Ok..I dont want blend google analytics event handling with other js code..

Comment: hm..interesting..I will post some code..Live version is on www.designclub.cz and what we are talking here about are links in "program" section..the boxes in the middle of the site..

Comment: ok I have updated the fiddle with my code..:)

Comment: I don't see your code there. Did you press the update? Or try fork, and send the new link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5qUrc/ actually is it working:)but on my site it isnt..hm

Answer (score 0):

Just place a `click(function(event) { ... })` handler on the static parent element, and find the element which started the event with `event.target`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `a` containing an `img`, any event on the `img` should bubble to the `a`, which will catch it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the .delegate() method (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Here is some more info regarding .live() vs. delegate():

- http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23Q4S9hmHQY
- [jQuery: live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate) [stackoverflow.com]

Update:

Here is a post by Jupiter 24 about "Why you should never use jQuery live":

- http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live