# Apply Function To An Object Which Is Inserted By JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function, which appends a div into a div(2). Inside div(2) I have a span. if I click this span, a function shall be executed.(click() function)

Currently I can not apply any function by onclick(), if div(2) gets inserted by jQuery.
 If I insert div(2) directly (hardcoded) I can execute the function.

How can I apply a function to an object which is inserted by jQuery?

Comment: Posting your code you can get a quick and better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to handle events for future elements — those which are not yet part of the DOM:

```
$(document).delegate(".div2 > span", "click", function () {
   // handle click event here
});
```

Comment: `.live` runs right away as well. The difference between them has to do with event bubbling

Comment: [`.delegate` is just more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate/4204349#4204349)

Comment: @SimpleCoder, @Raynos: you're both right - I had them the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to have your jQuery code that inserts the element also attach the click handler.

So extend your function that calls

`$(div).append(div2)`

To also call

```
$(div2).find("span").click(function() {

});
```