# simple jquery live(click) not working for some reason

Tags: jquery

If you check out http://social.allthingswebdesign.com, click the "get social" link and there are 6 icons. I'm trying to make the triangle appear under the icon is clicked.

I started with the code below, but I can't get anything to appear in the console in firebug. What's my deal?

```
$('.pic').live('click', function() {
    console.log('in here???');
});
```

Comment: are you adding ".pic" dynamically to the page? If not you can not use live(), your should use bind(), or click()

Comment: yes it's being added dynamcially

Comment: @valipour .live() works through event delegation. It doesn't matter if the object is there before or after the event is bound.

Comment: **Don't use `live`.** Be a man and `delegate` instead. `$('#idTabs').delegate('.pic','click', function() { . . .` Some discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate

Comment: @Levi Morrison that won't help at all in this case.  The "click" events are being killed by that "idtabs" plugin, so neither ".live()" nor ".delegate()" will work.

Comment: @Pointy, I know.  That's why its a comment, not an answer.  (Almost) no one should be using `live` anymore.  I'm just trying to spread the awareness.

Comment: Just a thought, but you need to look into one of the javascript templating libraries if you're going to have that much inline JS-HTML.  Go with jQuery's template() functions to render all that html, doin it the way you're doing it is quite hard to maintain in my opinion.

Comment: @Levi Morrison on that point we agree :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is very likely to be that that "tabs" plugin is killing your "click" events, preventing them from bubbling up to the body.

*edit* — it appears that that "tabs" plugin allows you to give it a "click" handler, which should I think return "true" to make it work:

```
$("ul.idTabs").idTabs({
  click: function() {
    console.log('in here???');
    $('#innest .idTabs li a').remove('#triangle');
    $(this).append('<img id="triangle" src="triangle.png" />');
    return true; // I think
  }
});
```

I don't know why you'd add all that HTML dynamically.  Why not just include it directly into the page and hide it until you need it?  It's really messy and error-prone to include lots of markup like that in the middle of your JavaScript code.

Comment: It's basically a plugin i'm developing that hasn't been packaged up yet. Do you have any ideas on how I can still get the triangle to appear under the icons when clicked?

Comment: Where the heck did you see something about a click event handler?  I see next to no documentation on the idTabs website.  I don't feel like that plugin is at all necessary, it takes a whopping 2 lines of code to make it work without using a silly plugin.

Comment: Click on the "Advanced" tab.  There's also a source viewer. I agree however that that site leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to create the tabs at the time and this plugin seemed simple enough. I got it so the triangles appear using your code, but I can't get any of them to remove on click.

Answer (score 1):

Drop idTabs and go with this:

```
$('.pic').live('click', function(){
  $('.contentArea').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).show();

  // Your triangle logic goes here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your idTabs plugin causing the problem, taking that out writes out the console.log.

I tried using the beta version from the dev's website but that continued to stop the rest working.

I would be tempted to write your own jQuery to do what you want, it will only be a few lines compared to a big plugin, and you can be sure it won't mess up anything else.