# Event not being triggered in jquery, what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I have four `<select>` element.

```
<div id="select-countries-container">
        <select name="countryId" id="select-countries">
            <option value="">Choose Country &raquo;</option>
        <?php foreach($location->fetch(array('table' => 'countries')) as $country) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country['id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="select-states-container"><select disabled="disabled"><option value="">Choose State &raquo;</option></select></div>
<div id="select-cities-container"><select disabled="disabled"><option value="">Choose City &raquo;</option></select></div>
<div id="select-areas-container"><select disabled="disabled"><option value="">Choose Area &raquo;</option></select></div>
```

the child element `<select>` is replaced with the code received from Ajax, here is the Ajax Code i am using.

```
$('#select-countries').change(function(){
    var countryId = $(this).val();
    if(countryId == ''){
        $('#select-states-container').html(chooseState);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'process.php',
            data: 'countryId='+countryId,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#select-states-container').html(loadingText);
            },
            success: function(states){
                if(states == 'null') {
                    $('#select-states-container').html(emptyState);
                } else {
                    $('#select-states-container').html(states);
                }   
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and the data being retrieved from process.php is.

```
$select  = '<select name="stateId" id="select-states">';
$select .= '<option value = "">Choose State &raquo;</option>';
foreach($states as $state) {
    $select .= '<option value = "'.$state['id'].'">'.$state['name'].'</option>';
}
$select .= '</select>';
echo $select;
```

till here it works perfectly fine, the trouble starts when i select states from second `<select>` i.e `<select name="stateId" id="select-states">` retrieved from process.php, when i select the value from this it does not trigger the function it is bound to, i am not sure what is happening, here is what i tried to do.

```
$('#select-states').change(function(){
        alert('Fire');
});
```

and this does not fire. what is wrong with my code?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

From the documentation:

> Description: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which
>   match the current selector, now and in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `delegate()` to add the change handler to dynamically-created elements:

```
$("body").delegate("#select-states", "change", function(){
    ...
```

This is necessary because your existing code runs only once ( when the document is loaded, presumably) and binds the event handler only to the elements that exist at that time. Delegate will bind the event all existing elements, **plus** all elements that are created in the future. For more information, please see the [jQuery delegate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

If you wish, you can use `bind()` instead. You would place the call to `bind()` in the AJAX call's success function to attach the event handler to the element after it is created.

**EDIT**

For a good analysis on the differences between `delegate()` and `live()`, see [jQuery: live() vs delegate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate)

Comment: If you're going to set it on `body`, why not just use `live`?

Comment: not sure but it is not working i tried using this code `$("body").delegate('#selected-states', 'change', function(){
 alert('fire');});` :(

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: '#selected-states' is not a valid identifier. Should it be '#select-states'?

Comment: @kingjiv: `live()` works fine in many cases, as long as you heed the many caveats listed in the documentation. `delegate()` is more flexible and applies to a wider variety of situations and events.

Comment: I guess I'll have to read up on it again.  I thought all of the same caveats applied to delegate except it was more targeted.

Comment: @George, how could be `#selected-states` not a valid identifier? i copy pasted the code from my script. i am really not sure on why isn't `.delegate()` working for me :(, is it okay for me to go with `.live()` ?

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: In your post, you said you defined your element as: `<select name="stateId" id="select-states">`. An selector of 'selected-states' will not match this element. Therefore, the `delegate()` call will have no effect.

Comment: so do you suggest i rename the selector and use `.delegate()`, i am a novice in JS, can `.live()` be problematic for me?

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: If `live()` works for you, you can use it (either way, your selector needs to match the element). Just keep in mind the [caveats in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats), and consider examining the link I added to my answer. `delegate()` is more efficient, and works in situations where `live()` may not.